# Flutter Doctor, Flutter & Dart plugin not installed

Tags: android, flutter

I have been already running flutter and android studio. Today i just updated the android studio to latest version 4.1 after upgrading when i run the flutter doctor. I am getting the following error.

[image]

I have installed flutter and dart plugins in the android studio.
[image]

Staring new flutter project is showing in the welcome screen [image]

But when i run the flutter doctor in the terminal its says Flutter plugin not installed. I have attached the vim bash file too[image]

I am not able to find whats the issue.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You cant fix it. This is Flutter bug.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68180

Just wait or back to android studio 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If you have `IntelliJ IDEA` in your computer try to delete and run `flutter doctor` again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. IntelliJ IDEA is not installed in my computer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, can you try to run: `flutter config --android-studio-dir='<path to android studio>'` to see if it can fix the issue.