# 'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

Recently installed flutter sdk, Android studio 4.1 and Flutter and Dart plugins for both VSCode and Android studio. Running `flutter doctor` gives me the following

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

A similar question has been asked [Flutter Doctor, Flutter & Dart plugin not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368957/flutter-doctor-flutter-dart-plugin-not-installed) which says its a bug in the 4.1 release, but the github repo says the bug has been fixed and to ignore the warning.
I've tried:

1)Disabling and Re-enabling the plugins

2)Reinstalling the plugins

3)Reinstalling both VSCode and Android Studio

4)Checking if the plugins are installed in the right place

5)Executing it on another emulator and device

When i execute

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; //for materials

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(
      color: Colors.purple,
    ),
  ));
}
```

This is the output i get in the debug console:

```
'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 677

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I hope you have restarted android studio after installation?

Comment: Did you install latest version of android sdk from sdk manager?

Comment: @ShripadJadhav yes, i have restarted every time after installing each plugin.

Comment: @HHooshyar yeah, i have the latest version installed.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Browse to the environment variable setting and update PATH variable to contain address for your System32 folder.

i.e C:\Windows\System32
After adding the variable, restart your computer.

It will fix the error.

Reason: This problem occurred because the system didn't found the 'attrib' file.