# flutter terminal keeps giving me error whenever i debug the my test codes

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[been getting this error when i try to run the min.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8L4l.png)

test code for my flutter dev

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843125/attrib-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors as text and format them as code and do not post images of code or error