# Error while running the emulator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

this error is showing while I run the emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUJ2x.png)

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: first line of error in your debug console - "attrib" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batchfile. so somewhere in your code "attrib" is 
missed typed and if you check "problem" section in console you will probably find where it is located.(if it's in your project)

Comment: See if it works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353811/13418864 After this Restart your Android Studio.